# how to manually lessc compile in django project?

Tags: django, less

I have a less file which looks like below

```
@static_url: "/static/";        //don't know how to use static tag or {{STATIC_URL}}                                                                                                                                                                                            

@import url("@{static_url}site_common/bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less");

@import url("@{static_url}momsplanner/custom_bootstrap/custom-variables.less");
@import url("@{static_url}momsplanner/custom_bootstrap/custom-other.less");

@import url("@{static_url}site_common/bower_components/bootstrap/less/utilities.less");
```

It works fine, but when I try to compile it with lessc, it's doable but very messy (i'll have to do collectstatic first, and give the STATIC_ROOT as lessc's include-path option)

I guess using relative path in the above less file is easier than that, are there other alternatives?

Comment: I typically pre-compile my Less files and only include links to the compiled CSS files in my templates.

Some alternatives to using JavaScript/Node at runtime to compile the files are to use Less2Css in SublimeText, or WinLess on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise using relative @imports.  I wrote a helper function to construct the include paths from the configured django INSTALLED_APPS since we're using `AppDirectoriesFinder` that you could adapt to your manual trans-compilation process (we use django-compressor):

```
from compressor.filters.base import CompilerFilter
from django.utils.functional import memoize

_static_locations = {}

def _get_static_locations():
    from django.conf import settings
    """
    Captures all the static dirs (both from filesystem and apps) for build an include path for the LESS compiler.
    """
    dirs = ['.']
    for dir in settings.STATICFILES_DIRS:
        dirs.append(dir)
    for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS:
        from django.utils.importlib import import_module
        import os.path
        mod = import_module(app)
        mod_path = os.path.dirname(mod.__file__)
        location = os.path.join(mod_path, "static")
        if os.path.isdir(location):
            dirs.append(location)
    return dirs

get_static_locations = memoize(_get_static_locations, _static_locations, 0)


class LessCompilerFilter(CompilerFilter):
    def __init__(self, content, command=None, *args, **kwargs):
        command = 'lessc --no-color --include-path=%s {infile} {outfile}' % ':'.join(get_static_locations())
        super(LessCompilerFilter, self).__init__(content, command, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I ended up using 'django-pipeline' and giving `PIPELINE_LESS_ARGUMENTS='--include-path='+os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, '..')`  Now I can use absolute path in the less file

Comment: Nice tip Kevin. I managed to get this working with `django-pipeline` using the same method and overriding `pipeline.compilers.less.LessCompiler`:

    ```class AppLessCompiler(LessCompiler):
        def compile_file(self, if, of, outdated=False, force=False):
            command = "%s %s %s > %s" % (
                settings.PIPELINE_LESS_BINARY,
                '%s --include-path=%s' % (
                    settings.PIPELINE_LESS_ARGUMENTS,':'.join(get_static_locations())
                ), if, of
            )
            return self.execute_command(command, cwd=dirname(if))```